# set timeout to notification javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a website notification When sending the notification, it is sent now. I want to send it two hours after pressing the send notification button

CODE

```
 <button onclick="bell();">send</button>
function bell() {
  function notifyMe() {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
      alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
    }
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
      notify();
    }
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
      Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
        if (permission === "granted") {
          notify();
        }
      });
    }
    
    function notify() {
      var notification = new Notification('success now', {
        icon: 'blue.svg',
      });
  

      setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 3000); 
      var notification = new Notification('success 2 hours', {
        icon: 'blue.svg',
      });      notification.onclick = function () {
        window.open("INDEX.HTML");      
      };
    }
  
  }
  notifyMe();
}
```

Comment: use `setTimeout` function. [Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the problem?

Comment: okay am using it this way and don't work

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to do it with JavaScript. A few seconds is one thing, but two hours? How will you make sure the website will still be opened in the client browser in two hours? Seems like you need a back-end solution and trigger it with your JavaScript.

Comment: Ok but what is the solution so this happened to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="bell()">Show notification</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const granted = (async () => {
            let granted = false;
            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                granted = true;
            } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
                let permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
                granted = permission === 'granted' ? true : false;
            }
            return granted;
        })();
        const showNotification = (msg) => {
            const notification = new Notification('success', {
                body: msg,
                icon: 'blue.svg'
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
                notification.close();
            }, 3 * 1000);

            notification.onclick = () => {
                window.focus();
            }
        }
        function bell() {
            granted && showNotification("Hello World"); // short for if (granted) showNotification(...)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```